# Laravel do not show category if foreach is empty

Tags: php, laravel, view, foreach, laravel-blade

I have the following controller and models:

Appointments Controller:

```
if ($view === 'default') {
    $appointments = Appointment::with('label')->with('status')->paginate(25);
}

if ($view === 'label') {
    $appointments = Label::with('appointments')->paginate(25);
}
```

Appointment Model:

```
public function label()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Label');
}
```

Label Model:

```
public function appointments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Appointment');
}
```

In my "default" view, the following is displayed:

[image]

And in my "label" view, the following is displayed:

[image]

What I want to accomplish is, when a label has no appointments, I do not want the label to be shown at all. So, in my "label view" (check out the below image) I only want the "business" and "personal" label (and it's appointments as shown in image) to be displayed, and all the other labels shouldn't be displayed.

In my views I am using simply foreach loops. Any pointers in the right direction?

My view (simple):

```
@if ($view === 'label')

    @foreach ($appointments as $appointment)

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th><p>{{ $appointment->label }}</p></th>
            </tr>

                @foreach ($appointment->appointments as $label)

                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $label->appointment }}</td>
                    </tr>

                @endforeach

        </table>

    @foreach ($appointments as $appointment)

@endif
```

Comment: can you post your view code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

You can achieve this by checking for non empty appointments. Here we would check for the negative case of ***empty ()*** method.

***View*** (blade)

```
@if ($view === 'label') 
    @foreach ($appointments as $appointment) 
       <table> 
          @foreach ($appointment->appointments as $key=> $label)
              @if(!empty($label))
                    @($key == 0)
                         <tr> 
                            <th><p>{{ $appointment->label }}</p> </th> 
                         </tr>
                    @endif 
                    <tr> 
                           <td>{{ $label->appointment }}</td> 
                    </tr> 
              @endif
           @endforeach 
        </table> 
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Very helpful indeed thanks, I was trying to figure it out but I failed, but your solution is the right one. Thanks again :)

Comment: I'm happy that I was able to help. I think the labels would get printed more than once if there is multiple appointments. Just now updated the answer

Comment: Thanks! I was just struggling with that :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the length of the array before you write the label. So here you'd make sure that $appointment->appointments count is greater than 0.

```
@if ($view === 'label')
    @foreach ($appointments as $appointment)
        @if (count($appointment->appointments) > 0)
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th><p>{{ $appointment->label }}</p></th>
            </tr>
                @foreach ($appointment->appointments as $label)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $label->appointment }}</td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
        </table>
        @endif
    @foreach ($appointments as $appointment)
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks, will see if I can work something out with this. Added my own simple version of my view in the OP.

Comment: @RonBrouwers Updated my answer to match your question.